# pixels are not scanned (c++ and opencv )

Tags: opencv

I have two questions about image processing. I want to multiply two image to achive only foreground image.
First question is,when ı run belong code but  have not good result(image link is https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5b8Wm-4Dlb6dkljSlowV3k3TE0/view?usp=sharing ). if ı write  i, all the picture pixels are not scanned. If ı wrtiei<400000` ı have good result more than first condition. But image size is 640*480. I cant solve that.

Other question is, When this function run in a loop (loop is a ROS loop that is operates 10 times per second) ,program is terminated. I dont understand why?

```
Mat depthSubtraction()
{
typedef ushort imgType;
    Mat sub=imread("/home/aylin/Desktop/sub.png");
    Mat dep=imread("/home/aylin/Desktop/depth.png");
    Mat a,b;
    imgType* m_a = NULL;
    imgType* m_b = NULL;
    imgType* m_c = NULL;

    int picWidth = dep.cols; //picture width
    int picHeight = dep.rows; //picture height

    Mat outputImg(picHeight,picWidth, dep.type()); //initialize the output image
    //memset(outputImg.data, 0, picWidth * picHeight*sizeof(imgType));//set the output image to zeros
    //outputImg=zeros(picHeight, picWidth, dep.type());


    m_a=(imgType*)sub.data;
    m_b=(imgType*)dep.data;
    m_c=(imgType*)outputImg.data;




    for(int i=0;i<picWidth*picHeight ;i++,m_a++,m_b++,m_c++)
    {
        if(*m_a<2)
        {
            *m_a=0;
            *m_c = (*m_a)*(*m_b);
            *m_b=0;

        }
        else
        {
            *m_a=1;
            *m_c = (*m_a)*(*m_b);
            *m_b=0;

        }
        cout<<*m_c<<" "<<*m_a<<endl;
    }

    cvtColor(outputImg, b, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    imshow("aaaa",b);
    imwrite("/home/aylin/Desktop/newww.png",b);
    waitKey();



   }


   int main(int argc, char **argv)
   {

/*
  init(argc, argv, "Aylin_node");

   Subscribe_Depth sd;

   Rate spin_rate(10);

   while( ok() ) {
    spinOnce();

    spin_rate.sleep();
    }

     */

depthSubtraction();



return 0;
   }
```

Comment: first of all, *don't* roll your own per-pixel loops. if you want to do an element-wise multiplication of 2 Mat's use `Mat c=a.mul(b);`.

Comment: then, the images you read, are of type Vec3b, not ushort, so your 'pointer magic' *must* explode.

Comment: then again, multiplying might be the wrong way. instead, read in your depth image properly (see imread docs), threshold it, and use it as a mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your imgType should be uchar instead of ushort.

Also since imread reads color image by default, your for loop should run picWidth*picHeight*3 times.

Other than that I don't see any problems with the code, however if I would try to achieve the same functionality, I would write it as follows:

```
Mat src = imead("image.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Mat mask = imread("mask.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

Mat dst = Mat::zeros(src.rows, src.cols, CV_8UC1);
src.copyTo(dst, mask);
```